# Azure Functions 3 on .NET Core 3.1 throwing OutOfMemoryException

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I recently updated my Azure Functions 2 app (targeting .NET Core 2.2) to Azure Functions 3 (targeting .NET Core 3.1). This upgrade included no code or logic changes, just framework and package updates.

This is the extent of the changeset.

**Previous Project File:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

**Updated Project File:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

I have an HTTP trigger function that reads data from Azure Table Storage database. This function has been working out in production for almost a year without any issues. After deploying the upgraded (v3) Functions app, I'm observing many occurrences of `OutOfMemoryException` during the invocation of the HTTP trigger function that reads data from Azure Table Storage. This results in a 500 response. The function does work without a `OutOfMemoryException` being thrown, occasionally. I can't figure out the difference between the successes and failures.

This is method in which the exception occurs:

```cs
private async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ExecuteQuery<T>(CloudTable table, TableQuery<T> query) where T : ITableEntity, new()
{
    var results = new List<T>();
    TableContinuationToken token = null;

    do
    {
        // Read entities from each query segment.
        var segment = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, token);
        token = segment.ContinuationToken;

        results.AddRange(segment); // Build collection of records.
    }
    while (token != null);

    return results;
}
```

Application Insights shows that this `do/while` loop successfully executes a query segment about four to six times (not consistent) before the `OutOfMemoryException` occurs. After hours of trying, I am unable to replicate this error locally, even pointing at the same Azure Table Storage instance.

I did change the Function app's `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` application setting from `~2` to `~3`.

There are several other HTTP trigger functions and timer trigger functions in this app that read/write data from other sources and are working without issue. There's even an HTTP trigger function that successfully writes data to the same Azure Table Storage table that causes issues during reads. For now, I have redeployed the build of my Azure Functions app that targets v2 (and there are no more `OutOfMemoryException`s).

Does anyone have any ideas on what I might have missed or what I could do to fix this `OutOfMemoryException` issue?

**UPDATE**

This `OutOfMemoryException` issue only occurs when the Azure Functions app platform is set to 64bit. When set to 32bit, the flurry of OutOfMemoryExceptions cease.

For anyone else who lands here looking for a solution, simply switch your functions app platform to 32bit until Microsoft resolves [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5430).

[image]

**UPDATE:**

For anyone reading this, Microsoft addressed [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5430) and released a fix in early Feb 2020.

Comment: I've been debugging this problem all day, also seems to have started after moving to ~3 and made some minor logging tweaks to code that had been running find for a year or more.  Will give the x86 setting a go as I'm also using x64.

Comment: @RayHayes - I've added an image of the Azure Functions setting I'm referring to, just in case. Let me know if your issues are resolved with a 32bit platform. You could also pipe in [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5430).

Comment: For anyone reading this, Microsoft addressed this issue and released a fix in early Feb 2020 (https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5430)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the memory is not enough, according to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits) we can know consumption plan just have 1.5GB max memory per instance.
[image]

So, if you choose consumption plan for your function, the memory may be scarce at times(
although it allows us to change the function app from 32bit to 64 bit in consumption). So we need to create an app service plan for it.

If you have already created an app service plan, I think you can have a try to scale up your app service plan for more memory size and see if the exception still shows.

By the way, here I provide a [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/) for details of app service plan for your reference.(according to this tutorial, we can know 64bit need app service plan tier higher than "Basic")
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @HuryShen. 1.5GB should be *way* more than enough to handle the few thousand records I'm querying and deserializing. I'd like to clarify, my app had been running without issue on a 64bit platform until upgrading from v2 to v3. Additionally, the v3 version of my app runs without issue on a 32bit platform.

Comment: Hi @TomFaltesek, have you tried to change the consumption plan with an app service plan and test if it still show this exception ?

Comment: I have not. It seems that [this is an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5430) that others are having with v3, as well.

Comment: Hi @TomFaltesek, so have you solved this issue ? If you solved the issue successfully, could you please add an answer under this post and mark yourself as "accepted", this can be beneficial to others, thanks~

Comment: Other than the 32bit workaround mentioned in the question, I have not come across a solution.

Comment: @TomFaltesek Maybe you can raise a support ticket on Azure portal by following the steps in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). The support team can see the backend code and help you on it.

Comment: Hi @HuryShen. A support ticket may not be a bad route, but I'm not interested in paying the [$30/month](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/): "Azure provides unlimited support for subscription management (things like billing, quota adjustments, and account transfers). For technical support, you need a support plan." Nevertheless, the Functions team is fully aware of this [potential issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5430).